# Asp .net mvc 4 specific "select ...." command

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make an ebank, for myself, so it is not that serious. This is my structure:
[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/rig0sx.png]

What I achieved so far: if a user logs in, and click on the Ebank actionlink, for him/her I display ALL of the data (I mean if logged in **userId==1** I display all of the data with **userId==2** too, this is what I want to change).

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

     var bankaccounts = db.BankAccounts.Include(b => b.Type).Include(b => b.Balance).Include(b => b.UserProfile);
     return View(bankaccounts.ToList());

}
```

This "var bankaccounts" row is what I have to change if I am right. If I put a breakpoint to the "return view(bankaccounts.ToList())" row I get the following data from the "bankaccounts":

```
    {
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[BankAccountId] AS [BankAccountId], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[AccountName] AS [AccountName], 
    [Extent1].[AccountType] AS [AccountType], 
    [Extent1].[AccountNumber] AS [AccountNumber], 
    [Extent1].[AccountStatus] AS [AccountStatus], 
    [Extent1].[AccountAvaiability] AS [AccountAvaiability], 
    [Extent2].[AccountType] AS [AccountType1], 
    [Extent2].[TypeName] AS [TypeName], 
    [Extent3].[BalanceId] AS [BalanceId], 
    [Extent3].[BalanceAmount] AS [BalanceAmount], 
    [Extent3].[TrustAmount] AS [TrustAmount], 
    [Extent4].[UserId] AS [UserId1], 
    [Extent4].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM    [dbo].[BankAccount] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Type] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AccountType] = [Extent2].[AccountType]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Balance] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[BankAccountId] = [Extent3].[BalanceId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserProfile] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent4].[UserId]}
```

**Questions:**

I cannot find any real sql command in the code(its auto generated by mvc), so If I am right

1. does this "var bankaccounts" row do the sql select?
2. If yes, how?
3. Where can I read after this type of programming?
4. I want to change this code to something like "select ... where userid == websecurity. CurrentUserId", can you help me with this please?
5. Any more ideas, advices that I should take or read after? The more you say the more I can learn!

Comment: Welcome to LINQ world, you can run sql scripts using `DBQuery`. checkout this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Comment: You should Google the term "Object Relational Mapper". This answers all of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a provider like Entity Framework which is providing the mapping from code to your database. Specifically:

1. In your case, the Sql gets executed when you materialize the query with `ToList()`. Until the materialization step, `var bankaccounts` is an `IQueryable`.
2. Entity Framework has a Query provider which knows how to parse the Expressions you give it to Sql statements, and similarly, to map result sets back to entities like `BankAccount`.
3. [Sites like MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you an overview
4. Add a `Where` expression predicate:

```
var userBankaccounts = db.BankAccounts
                         .Where(ba => ba.UserId == websecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

The Sql you see is 'real' (sans the curly {} brackets) - once you look past the rather annoying aliasing of tables and derived tables as `[Extentxxx]`, it will allow you to quickly check that your Linq expressions are performing the queries required.